# Is there any CombineParquetFileInputFormat exist?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, parquet, bigdata

In my project I have to read parquet files threw MapReduce. There a lots of parquet files with small size. I need some Combine Parquet Input Format which can combine the small files according to the split size so that number of Mappers will be less. Please let me know if there exist some utility or any simple way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ParquetInputFormat is child of FileInputFormat which supports multiple file input.
So, in short, you just do not need CombileParquetFileInputFormat

Just use FileInputFormat.addInputPaths to specify inputs.

Sources of ParquetInputFormat
https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetInputFormat.java

P.S. If you have a lot of small parquet files there is a probability that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: But adding paths to FileInputFormat will not cause to create less number of mappers if file sizes are less then max input split size. In this way number of mappers will be number of input files.

Comment: @agarwal_achhnera it seems you are right. As far as I see the ParquetInputSplit contains only one path. So one split could not contains blocks from different files.

Comment: exactly , that's the main issue due to which I get stuck as ParquetInputSplit contains only one path so one file can be divided into multiple splits but more then one file can't be refer to one split. If still you have any alternate idea for this that's welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReaderWrapper; import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileSplit; 
import parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport; 
import parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class CombineParquetInputFormat<T> extends CombineFileInputFormat<Void, T> {


        @Override
        public RecordReader<Void, T> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext
                context) throws IOException {
            CombineFileSplit combineSplit = (CombineFileSplit) split;
            return new CombineFileRecordReader(combineSplit, context, CombineParquetrecordReader.class);
        }

        private static class CombineParquetrecordReader<T> extends CombineFileRecordReaderWrapper<Void, T> {


            public  CombineParquetrecordReader(CombineFileSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context, Integer idx) throws
                    IOException, InterruptedException {
                super(new ParquetInputFormat<T>(AvroReadSupport.class), split, context, idx);
            }
        } }
```

A awesome blog about the same with Integration test
    http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/combineparquetfileinputformat/